# Merge multiple large dataframes with many non-matching columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I've got a list of around 140 data frames, all of which have different number of rows and columns. The only thing they have in common is that they have `sample ID` as rownames and `years` as columns. The years are between 1400-2018 and different data frames have samples in different time periods between those dates. Hence, some columns are matching (i.e. all data frames have values in those years), while others are not (e..g only 1 or 2 dataframes have values in these years). An example of a data frame is shown below:

```
> dput(shell[[20]])
  list(structure(list(`1847` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.33, 
                                NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
                                ), `1848` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.86, 1.46, NA, NA, NA, 
                                NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `1849` = c(NA, 
                                NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.75, 1.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `1850` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                NA, 1.7, 1.23, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 

                                                ...
```

I want to merge these data frames so that rownames are kept (i.e. simply pasting them below each other) and values in columns are matched - i.e. if a given sample has values between 1650-1700 these are retained, and for `years` where that sample has no value there is `NA`. I also need the years to follow from earliest to present. So, I want it to look like this:

```
.. 1847  1848  1849 ... 
S1  NA   NA    NA
S2  12.5  3.5  4.5
S3  NA   NA    12.5
```

I've tried doing this with `bind_rows` and `rbind.fill` and it works for some columns, but not others - I got some very strange columns (e.g. columns names `-150` in the middle of the data).

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Please share the entire output of your `dput` otherwise it is of little use. If the data is too big you can share `dput(head(my_data))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert your `data.frames` into `data.table` objects, you can try the following:

```r
library(data.table)
lapply(shell, setDT)
```

Then, you can use `rbindlist` function that is very efficient and powerful:

```r
data <- rbindlist(shell, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```

Finally, to reorder the columns, you can use `setcolorder`. Something in this flavor (you might need to adapt it a little bit) :

```r
years <- as.character(1400:2018)[as.character(1400:2018) %in%  colnames(data)]
setcolorder(data, c("sampleID", years))
```